# Managing hierarchical data in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, xml, database, data-structures

Currently I am researching on managing hierarchical data (from XML) in C/C++. I need to parse XML files and store them in a DB effectively, so I should be able to query the DB later on. Any suggestions on this are most welcome.

I came across [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).
This looks good, but still wondering if there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing C++ XML parser such as Xerces?

Comment: Hi Billy,

Does Xerces provides any MYSQL specific functionalities? I am looking for an API that also helps me store, retrieve and manage data in the Database.

Thanks

Comment: @user803969: No, but MySQL provides an API, and Xerces provides an API... you wouldn't need to build a hierarchical representation yourself. That all said, be warned -- SQL HATES hierarchical data.

Comment: No sure I understand. Can you give me some links that would make me understand it better. How can I use these two APIs together to eliminate the hierarchical representation of the data.

Comment: @ddama: By writing a program. Xerces gives you programmatic representation of the XML. MySQL gives you a way to run SQL queries. You will have to write the glue.

Comment: (Unfortunately MySQL does not come with good tools for extracting data out of non-SQL data sources, as, say, MSSQL does with SQL Server Integration Services)

Comment: @Billy: Thanks, this solved my query. I do have a code in place that uses expat library for XML parsing, and libsqlite3 for SQL stuff. Was just curious, if there exists an amalgamation of two.

Answer (score 0):

If you read closely the document, you'll find there are 2 ways stored hierarchical data, one using a "parent_ID", another using "left_sibling_ID" & "right_sibling_ID".

I suggest use the first one:

myxmltable = {myxmltable_ID, myxmltable_parent_ID, myxmltable_otherfield_1, ...}

Additionally, you could store all your items, with an key > 0. The parent key for the root item could be 0, meaning, it has no parent. I suggest avoid using NULL, in order to make more easy to handle your D.B. and use 0 instead.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this. I appreciate it.

Comment: Is there an existing API that does these operations or will I have to write one of my own?

Comment: I ignore f there is an special libary / API in C/C++ to store from an XML file into an specific D.B. S.Q.L. server, but, you may want to look in common C/C++ libraries like Boost

Answer (score 0):

XML stores hierarchical data which does not fit well with the relational approach of SQL. I would strongly suggest you look at XPath/XQuery, which are query languages that operate on the XML directly. Qt contains an XQuery library that I've used with good results.